# JQuery - Problema com eventos MouseEnter() & MouseLeave()

Tags: jquery, eventos, eventos-do-mouse

## Situação:

- Tenho um menu, e preciso que quando ocorra um evento de `hover`, ele
  exiba uma série de informações do respectivo menu
- Quando o mouse for para outro menu, as informações exibidas tem que ser escondidas e mostrar as informações do outro menu.

## Problema:

- Quando eu passo o mouse rapidamente nos links do menu, as vezes ele acaba bugando, exibindo o conteúdo de 2 menus ou mais (que não deu tempo de esconder)

## [Aqui está o JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lolz1mkuroski/d67Z8/1/)

**Segue abaixo o código que estou usando:**

## HTML:

```html
<ul class="megamenu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="sbc_1">Teste</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="sbc_2">Teste2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="sbc_3">Teste3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-id="sbc_4">Teste4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## JS:

```js
$(function(){
    var id;

    $('.megamenu a').mouseenter(function()
    {
        id = '#megamenuContent #'+$(this).data("id");
        $(id).fadeIn('slow');
    })
    .mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(id).hide();
    });
});
```

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma sugestão ou alguma solução para este problema, em um último caso eu acabarei optando por utilizar o evento  `click`, mas o ideal para o meu caso eh utilizar o `hover`.

Comment: Não use mouseenter pois seu site não vai ficar bacana num touchscreen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Resposta:

Seu problema é pelo fato das animações não terem tempo suficiente para terminar antes que você inicie outra.

## Solução:

Você pode utilizar o evento `.stop()` com o intuito de parar propagação da animação antes de iniciar outra, que no caso seria recomendado no momento exato antes de iniciar uma nova animação você parar a mesma.

Em seu código a aplicação desta função poderia ser feita desta forma:

```js
$(function(){
    var id;

    $('.megamenu a').mouseenter(function()
    {
        id = '#megamenuContent #'+$(this).data("id");
        $(id).stop().fadeIn('slow'); //note que aqui eu adicionei a função .stop() para parar a propagação, logo antes do início do efeito.
    })
    .mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(id).hide();
    });
});
```

## Explicação:

Bem esse tipo de problema é comum em animações, pois elas duram um certo tempo pré determinado por você. Qualquer tipo de animação deve ser visto como você pode trata-la para que nunca ocorra uma sobreposição de animações, dessa forma acontecendo o seu problema, por isso parar animações decorrentes com certeza é a melhor forma de resolver isto.

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d67Z8/2/)

Comment: Era exatamente isto, muito obrigado mesmo.

Eu imaginei que o problema era a animação, mas não fazia ideia de como arrumar isto. Fiz o que você disse, e entendi a explicação, valeu mesmo =D

Comment: Disponha. Estou aqui pra isso :}

Answer (score 3):

Adicione a função `stop` antes da função `fadeIn` ficando assim: `$(id).stop().fadeIn('slow')`

Comment: Funciona! Porém, daria pra elaborar um pouco mais a resposta para não ficar algo tão seco?